# Wrong URL in Yii html:a

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My code is doesn't work property.

```
echo Html::a($podkategoria->nazwa, ["/wybierz/kategoria", 'kategoriaId' => $podkategoria->id], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']);
```

Is making link `"wybierz/kategoria/1"` and from action I getting the following error:

> Missing required parameters: kategoriaId

My action

```
public function actionKategoria($kategoriaId)
```

Comment: what parameter you describe in the urlManager rules for this route?

Comment: i fix it 
solution ->     'rules' => [
                '<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>' ,
    ],

Comment: Try with this 
$url='path'
echo Html::a('<button class="btn btn-primary "><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>', $url, [
                     'title' => 'title'
                     ]);

Comment: @ArshadShaikh excuse me, but u have no idea how to use framework. Don't use something like in this example.

Comment: @Yupik. Sorry for that but we can you this.
I think just print out the  $_GET on first line of action
public function actionKategoria()
{
     echo "<pre>";print_r($_GET);die;
}
will solve issue :)